# How to send emails with yahoo account while using outlook so that sender name is not just my email address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

How to send emails with yahoo account while using outlook so that sender name is not just my email address

I have connected my yahoo email account to outlook. Now when I send email on this yahoo account using outlook, people that receive my email sees that it's from my yahoo's email account name, instead of my actual name like it does if I send from yahoo mail directly. Let me clarify with a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2nc8.jpg

If I send from yahoo mail's interface, I get the bottom result where it says "James Bell"

If I send from outlook interface, I get the top result where it has my actual email address.

I want to get it so when I send from outlook I get the bottom result (aka James Bell). How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change the display name that e-mail recipients see](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-display-name-that-e-mail-recipients-see-2b53331a-ba2a-4803-88dc-ac9fe376c8a9)

Outlook 2016/2013:

1. In Outlook, choose File > Account Settings > Account Settings.
2. Select the email account that you want to change, and then choose Change.
3. You can change any of the information on the POP and IMAP Account settings page, including name, email address, and password.

Change the `Your Name:` field.

If this doesn't work

1. Repeat Steps 1 and 2, then choose More Settings
2. Choose the Outgoing Server tab
3. Make sure `My Outgoing server (SMTP) requires authentication` is checked
4. Select `Use same settings as my incoming mail server`